# How to check for all the files in a folder that containing a specific number?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to check all the filename in a folder and return a 'Pass' if all the filename are containing B3's value (1.1), return 'Fail' if one of the filename is not containing B3's value (1.1).

I had already try below codes, but it will return 'Pass' when any one of the filename containing B3's value (1.1).

```
Found = Dir(Path & "\" & "*" & Range("B3") & "*")

If Found <> "" Then
    Range("C3,C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Range("C3,C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below goes through all files in a folder and checks their names. If one of them does not include the value of `Range("B3")` then `found` will be `false`, while if all files have `Range("B3")` in their name `found` will be `true`.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim found As Boolean

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\testFolder")

    found = True
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If InStr(objFile.Name, Range("B3")) = 0 Then
            found = False
            Exit For
        End If

    Next objFile

    If found = True Then
        Range("C3,C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        Range("C3,C5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

End Sub
```

You can change "C:\testFolder" with any folder address you want to search in.